# How do I stop while loop when randint = 1

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi I have been constructing this code but I need to stop the while loop when the dice lands on a one.

```
    from random import randint 
    min = 1
    max = 6
    roll=input ('care to roll?')
    while roll == ('yes' or 'Yes'):
     print ("rolling...")
     print randint(min,max)
     print randint(min,max)
     while randint (1):
      break
    else:
      continue
    if roll == ('no' or 'No'):
     print ("fine then, see if I care")
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? The way to stop a `while` loop from executing is to add a condition such as `while result != 1`. You can store the result of the throw to a variable `result = randint(min,max)`

Comment: Note, `while roll == ('yes' or 'Yes')` is **not doing what you think it is doing**

Comment: consider checking `roll.lower()` against one value

Answer (score 1):

First, your else statement is not having if, there's a red flag. And your first while statement will not work if "Yes" given as input. You can use roll.lower() to check against one input only.
Try this:

```
from random import randint 

min = 1
max = 6
roll=raw_input('care to roll?').lower()

while roll == 'yes':
    print roll
    print ("rolling...")
    random_num = randint(min, max)
    if random_num==1:
      print "Sorry 1 came!!!"  
      break

if roll == 'no':
    print ("fine then, see if I care")
```

Also, a suggestion if you inserting a code snippet paste it then select the code and use {} during edit, it will indent code for you. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Store the roll value for the following break test

```
from random import randint 
min = 1
max = 6
roll = input('care to roll?')
while roll == 'yes' or roll == 'Yes':
  print ("rolling...")
  die = randint(min,max)
  print(die)
  if die == 1:
    break
  roll = input ('care to roll?')
if roll == 'no' or roll == 'No':
  print("fine then, see if I care")
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this out.

Comment: Also, consider not masking built-in functions `min` and `max`. And using `raw_input` in Python 2.

Comment: @Milk no - the point randomir is making is that you *shouldn't mask builtin functions with your own variables*

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to build a "Russian roulette" program with the following properties:

- Keep playing as long as the player wants it;
- When the player throws 1: he dies;

You could something like this:

```
from random import randint

while input("Wanna play Russian roulette?") in ('yes', 'Yes', 'yup',):
    throw = randint(1,6)
    if throw == 1:
        print("You die")
        break
    print("The result was", throw, "you live")
```

Note that you have no reason to use variables `min` and `max` (which is bad naming practice anyways, because they hide the built-in functions `min` and `max`), as you can supply these directly to the `randint()` function.

Edit: since I did your homework for you, here are some suggestions to make it a bit more interesting:

- Let the player choose from 1 to 6 which will be the fatal throw. Make sure the player enters an integer and the value is between 1 and 6.
- Tell the player how many times he survived the game.

Comment: Yeah I'll also try that

Comment: Please consider upvoting / accepting answers that were useful to you (not specifically mine). That will help future visitors with similar problems.